# QML variable scope issues

Tags: qt, variables, scope, qml, closures

I am trying to use a property of the top-most component in the QML file inside a javascript function within some deeply nested structure, but it I'll get an error stating the property/variable name is undefined.

The confusing part is, that access to that very variable works in the line before.

Here's a part of the QML:

```
Page {
   id: page
   property var modelParam
   property var albumNameParam

   SilicaGridView {
      id: grid
      header: PageHeader { title: albumNameParam }
      cellWidth: width / 3
      cellHeight: width / 3
      anchors.fill: parent
      model: page.modelParam

      delegate: GridItem {
         id: gridItem
         menu: ContextMenu {
            MenuItem {
               text: qsTr("Delete" )
               onClicked: {
                  var dialog = pageStack.push(...)

                  dialog.accepted.connect(function() {
                     var res = modelParam.deleteSelected();   // works

                     modelParam.clearSelection();             // gives error
                  })
               }
            }
```

One solution I have found to this is:

```
               onClicked: {
                  var theModel = modelParam
                  var dialog = pageStack.push(...)

                  dialog.accepted.connect(function() {
                     var res = theModel.deleteSelected();   // works

                     theModel.clearSelection();             // works
                  })
               }
```

In this case, probably, the variable gets captured in the JS closure and is thus available inside the callback function.

However I don't understand how the first example can work ***partially***? What is the proper approach in this case?

Comment: I would say try to qualify modelParam in both cases (use page.modelParam) to make sure there are no duplicate definitions being used. Beyond that I don't see an immediately obvious issue, so I suggest you update your question with a MWE.

Comment: I have tried that, in this case, I will get errors about `page` being undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
page.modelParam.clearSelection();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).